# Purpose of ending this sentence with noun + が

Tags: particle-が

The sentence is

> 総務から領収書出せって連絡が

But I can't understand the purpose of 連絡が

I remember reading once that (noun + が)'s can sometimes be moved to the front of the sentence and still hold the same meaning, so I'm not sure if that's the case for this? Would it also make sense to say

> 連絡が総務から領収書出せって

too? And if so, what is the purpose of switching it? Are there any implications added?

Comment: "(noun + が)'s can sometimes be moved to the front of the sentence and still hold the same meaning" what are you mentioning in particular? I think Japanese word order (arrangement of noun phrases) is free in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

[a 総務から領収書出せって] 連絡が (ありました。omitted)

I think [a] is a clause which modifies/elaborates 連絡 so you won't be able to move them around.

When you have a direct object/location words before Nounが then you can switch their places and it would make sense.

> 映画を彼が　＝　彼が映画を

> 車の中で彼女が　＝　彼女が車の中で